# Improved approach of aligning vertically

Tags: html, css

Using CSS I am trying to center align, both vertically and horizontally, the company tagline as well as "learn about what we do":

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/7P2DH/10/embedded/result/

The issue with the approach i've used is, the text isnt even centered vertically or horizontally within the message div, so although the div is centered, my text isnt.

For my given use case am I better making my site one giant table, or is there a better solution (which is compatible with older browsers)

```
<td> using valign="middle"
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#message{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Pretty close but it sits too high up: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/7P2DH/13/embedded/result/